# Visual Studio 2013 release .exe doesn't start all projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, configuration, release

I've made a project with the following structure:

[project-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syZsQ.png)

And those are the startup-properties:

[startup-properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcKYB.png)

If I start the project in visual studio 2013 (release build) it works fine, but if I am starting the release .exe from the Release folder, only the first program does start ("Messwertanalyse").

Btw: It's a Wcf project, "Messwertanalyse" includes a wcf host (service, interface and so on)  and "Testclient" is a console-application which consumes a service from "Messwertanalyse". There are no NuGets installed.

Does somebody know this problem or could tell me, how I probably can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each project is what it is: a single project. It's not because you can group projects in a solution that they are "included" with eachother

Comment: But why am I able to start them all in visual studio?

Comment: Because they're in a solution. Your .exe isn't a solution but one of the projects in a solution.